# Downsampling the wavelength spacing of spectral radiance

Tags: units

I have spectral radiance measurements, $L_e$, that I need to downsample, and I want to make sure I do this correctly. Let's say the measurements are a constant value of $5\times 10^{-3}\: \rm W \: m^{-2} \: sr^{-1} \: nm^{-1}$ from 380 nm to 730 nm, at a spacing of $\underline{1 nm}$. I would like to downsample the existing $L_e$ data to $\underline{10 nm}$ spacing from 400 nm to 700 nm. Do I just multiply my existing $L_e$ values by 10 because the spacing is $10\times$ larger, so they become $5\times 10^{-2}\: \rm W \: m^{-2} \: sr^{-1} \: nm^{-1}$?

Comment: I don't understand. You're measuring radiance and you want to infer spectral radiance? If so, how are you splitting the incoming beam into different wavelength? In most cases, the constants in the conversion will *not* come from the spacing of your sampling and they will come from the bandwidth of your monochromator.

Comment: Also: we use MathJax on this site to typeset mathematics; for a tutorial, see [this thread on the mathematics site](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020).

Comment: Emilio, my measurements of a spectral radiance come from a spectroradiometer. The data that it collects is spectral radiance vs. wavelength at 1 nm spacing, but I need the same data at 10 nm spacing (to use a certain formula which expects 10 nm input).  So I want to  translate my existing 1-nm data to 10-nm spacing. I think I just multiply the spectral radiance values by 10 since the spacing is 10X bigger, but I want to make sure. [Thanks for the head's up on MathJax!]

Comment: Frankly, I don't think this can be solved online - you'd need to refer to your device's manual to understand exactly how it is converting from sampling to spectral radiance. Chances are that the naive understanding works, but it's impossible to tell for sure without the manual (and therefore without the precise reference to the device model).

Comment: Your units are ***per nm***. Multiplying by 10 for $10nm$ would be incorrect in any case.

Comment: npojo - I was talking with a more knowledgeable colleague than me, and he gave me the same answer as you: the values would be $5\times 10^{-3}\: \rm W \: m^{-2} \: sr^{-1} \: nm^{-1}$ even if I downsample to $10 nm$, $20 nm$, etc.

Comment: npojo, if you make your comment an answer I will accept it.